# JavaFX: Remove spaces from TextField using TextFormatter

Tags: javafx, textfield

I am trying to make a small program that searches words in vocabulary in JavaFX. I have a TextField where a user can specify the searched word. Search does not work if there are spaces. I tried to use TextFormatter to remove spaces from there.

```
        searchField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>((Change change) -> {
        String newText = change.getControlNewText();
        if (newText.matches(" ")) {
            change.setText(change.getText().replace(" ", ""));
            return change;
        }
        if (newText.matches("[A-Z]*")) {
            change.setText(change.getText().toLowerCase());
            return change;
        }
        return change;
    }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `controlNewText` property contains all the text after the edit. The only case where this could match `" "` is if you start with an empty `TextField` and press space. The only case when this matches `"[A-Z]*"` is when all the chars in the `TextField` are uppercase; it doesn't match, if the content of the `TextField` is `foo` and you add a `B`.

Also you need to take into account that

- The user may copy & paste text into the `TextField` resulting in the `text` property containing more than a single char
- Multiple chars could be selected and the fixed text may not match the original edit in length requiring you to adjust the selection range

This should satisfy your requirements (or at least come close enough for you to finish the code yourself):

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
TextFormatter<?> formatter = new TextFormatter<>((TextFormatter.Change change) -> {
    String text = change.getText();

    // if text was added, fix the text to fit the requirements
    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
        String newText = text.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();

        int carretPos = change.getCaretPosition() - text.length() + newText.length();
        change.setText(newText);

        // fix carret position based on difference in originally added text and fixed text
        change.selectRange(carretPos, carretPos);
    }
    return change;
});
textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```